# Lipschitz functions on $\mathbb R^n$ that (nearly) saturate the Lipschitz inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

For a 1-Lipschitz function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, we have $|f(x) - f(y)| \le | x - y|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$ and there is a function, namely $f(x) = x$ that achieves the inequality for all $x$ and $y$.

Now consider a 1-Lipschitz function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ satisfying the inequality
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(y)| \le \|x-y\|_2, \;\forall x,y \in \mathbb R^n 
\end{align*}
**Deterministic problem.** Is there a Lipschitz function that achieves the inequality or comes close to it say $|f(x)-f(y)| \ge c \|x-y\|_2$  for *most* $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for  the deterministic question: You cannot have  a Lipschitz function with $|f(x)-f(y)| \geq c \|x-y\|$ unless $n=1$. Such a function would be a homeomorphism. But you cannot have a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R^{n} $ into $\mathbb R$ unless $n=1$.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Did not notice that!